# Listing all selected terms for custom taxonomies on a post

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm running a query on a custom post type to display on a page. The custom post type has multiple custom taxonomies. Each taxonomy is not required. I want to display only the taxonomy terms selected, and not the others. How would I achieve this?

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'inspirations', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
    $loop->the_post();

    echo '<div class="inspirations-post '. wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'collections') . '">';
    the_title();
    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
    the_excerpt();
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
endwhile;
```

Right now this returns Array() when printed. I'm guessing I need to break apart the array somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'inspirations', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );  
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );  

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
    $loop->the_post();  

    $collections = '';
    foreach ( (array) wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'collections') as $collection ) {
        if ( empty($collection->slug ) )
            continue;

        $collections .= ' collection-' . sanitize_html_class($collection->slug, $collection->term_id);
    }

    echo '<div class="inspirations-post '. $collections . '">';
        the_title();  
        echo '<div class="entry-content">';  
            the_excerpt();  
        echo '</div>';  
    echo '</div>';  
endwhile;
```